# I need info on using NSUserDefaults in Xcode

Tags: xcode, nsuserdefaults

I came across this information in the posting of a question I found on here:

"Apple has added an extra rule for apps being submitted to the app store.

We can no longer store arbitrary data files in the Documents folder. Only content generated by the user like a text file they manually typed and saved or a photo they took with the camera can be saved in the Documents folder.

We are now expected to store our app generated files in the Library/Cache folder instead of the Documents folder. In addition, we should mark the files we don't want to be sync to iCloud with the skip backup attribute.

Failure to comply with this will result in an app being rejected by Apple.

Reason: The Documents folder is now used for syncing to iCloud. iCloud does a sync every few minutes and if we were to have megabytes of our app generated files stored in the Documents folder, it would get mixed up with the user's own iCloud synced files."

This makes me wonder if the way I have used NSUserDefaults in my app is "legal" in the eyes of apple.

I'm making a simple app that takes user input in about five different places. I'm saving these simple strings in NSUserDefault variables.

My question to anyone that fully understands the statements made within the quotes above is:

Am I saving data in a way that is no longer allowed by apple?

I'm new to the development game, and the information within quotes doesn't make it clear to me (in the context of my app's situation) whether I'm in the wrong or not.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSUserDefault is the official, supported way of storing user preferences. If that's what you're storing, then it's the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thank you Catfish_Man (Lmfao)! Can you enlighten me some more? Where in a project's files does NSUserDefaults save data? Thanks again!

Comment: Technically, it's not guaranteed to go in any particular place (the storage format and location is an implementation detail). In practice, for a sandboxed OSX app, it goes in ~/Library/Containers/<app bundle identifier>/Data/Library/Preferences/<app bundle identifier>.plist